# Quick trivial trigonometry question for polar form complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

The question that I am about to ask is quite trivial, but I don’t understand it perfectly.

I am solving complex numbers in polar form.

$$w=-1+i$$
When I want to get the angle $\phi $. I do:

$$\phi=\arctan(\frac{1}{-1})+\pi$$

So the question is that the we have two solutions of arctan; $3\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ both of these solutions give me different outcome when I put the angle in $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Should I only do one solution or should I do both. Am I missing a trivial understanding of trigonometry?

Comment: $3\pi /4$ is correct, $-\pi /4$ is not. Plot the point and note that the argument lies between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.

Comment: In fact $\phi=-\pi /4$ is for $1-i$ not for $-1+i$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the $+\pi$ that I written is only there to add to $-pi/4$ that I get $\phi=3\pi/4$.

Comment: The $+\pi $outside of $\arctan$ is there because we written so in our lectures. Because if I add that to $3\pi/4$ then I get $7\pi/4$. That is where the problem arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for the angle between the positive x-axis and the point =−1+. Of course there are many solutions for this since we can continue rotating 2 around the axis, but we usually take   to be between 0 and 2. So actually −/4  is the angle w makes with the negative x-axis so we add  to find the angle it makes with the positive x-axis. Hence =3/4 is the correct answer. It is easier to understand if you do a simple sketch.

Comment: This answers the question of my comment in the main post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one of the two solutions. To figure out which one, I would recommend plotting the complex plane, the point $w$ and the two angles.